# Implement mobilefirst service in ios app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In IBM bluemix, i basically have to use mobileFirst service to host my ios application being implemented in it. I have seen several tutorials and stack overflow search for that but didn't got any satisfactory answer from that. If you can provide any sequential tutorial for that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set up your Mobile Foundation service instance, as instructed in the following doc: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/
2. Create an iOS application. It can be a native app or a Cordova app with the iOS platform.
3. Add the MobileFirst SDK to the application by following the instructions per the required platform, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/
4. Register the application in the server. You can do this either via CLI or via a graphical interface. You can see a "quick start" way, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/

   Basically, to register an app from the command-line, simply navigate to the app root folder and run the command: `mfpdev app register`.
5. To ensure the connection between the server and client, you can make a simple call to obtain a token. You can find this code in the Quick Start docs mentioned above.

   - For iOS, be sure to enable "Keychain Sharing" in Xcode.